# c language - can I use const uint32_t instead of #define

Tags: c, microprocessors

In the code below, could I use `const uint32_t PERIPH_BASE_ADDR = 0x40000000;` instead of using a `#define`?

```
#ifndef MEMORY_MAP_H_
#define MEMORY_MAP_H_

#include <stdint.h>

// Base address for devices on the STM32F10x
#define PERIPH_BASE_ADDR ((uint32_t)0x40000000) // Peripheral base address in the alias region

// Peripheral memory map
#define AHB1_BASE_ADDR    ((uint32_t)(PERIPH_BASE_ADDR + 0x20000)) // Advanced High-performance Bus 1

#endif /* MEMORY_MAP_H_ */
```

Comment: Did you try it?...

Comment: If you put it in a header file, you should use `static const`.

Comment: @blatinox: Definitions should not get into a header file! This is C and `const` has different semantics than in C++.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can. In the header file, just put

```
static const uint32_t PERIPH_BASE_ADDR = (uint32_t) 0x40000000;
static const uint32_t AHB1_BASE_ADDR = (uint32_t) (PERIPH_BASE_ADDR + 0x20000);
```

The #define directive is a preprocessor directive; the preprocessor replaces those macros by their body before the compiler even sees it. Think of it as an automatic search and replace of your source code.

A const variable declaration declares an actual variable in the language, which you can use... well, like a real variable: take its address, pass it around, use cast it, convert it, etc.

Oh, performance: Perhaps you're thinking that avoiding the declaration of a variable saves time and space, but with any sensible compiler optimisation levels there will be no difference, as constant values are already substituted and folded at compile time. But you gain the huge advantage of type checking and making your code known to the debugger, so there's really no reason not to use const variables.

Comment: You can use compilation option (`-g3` for gcc) to have some information about macros in the debugger.

Comment: @blatinox Yeah Correct

Comment: C does not have constants like C++. Thie will generate different code and has different semantics. For embedded systems, this is the wrong approach.